# Java Multi-dimensional Array Average

Tags: java, arrays, function

Basically I have an array which holds rain data from years 1907-2007 (for example - length 100).
Each element of the array contains another array with data on the amount of rain each month in that year.

My question is, how would I go about calculating the average rainfall for a user specified year?
This is what I have so far:

```
public double calculateAverageForYear(int year){

double sum = 0.0;

for (int i=0;i<Years.length;i++){ 
sum = sum += Years[i].calculateAvgRain();
}
sum = sum/12;
return sum;
}
```

calculateAvgRain is defined in another class and is correct as far as my testing goes.
Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the signature of `Years[i].calculateAvgRain()` as in, does it accept the thing to do average over, or is it a method of an `Year` class?

Comment: Does this code not work? If not, then describe the problem.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 the expected answer is 10 units off my actual answer.

Comment: @Anly it is a method of another class that is set to calculate the average rainfall

Comment: @AcidMicrowave that much is clear. What troubles me is that you are asking a question, when that same method should do exactly what you want. And since you are asking, I assume it does not. So what is it?

Comment: Btw, you should use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), not [PascalCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase), for variable names. It is confusing otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the user-defined parameter `int year` is not the actual index to the `years` array. If it is an actual year number, you'll have to convert it depending on which is the first year in your array. It should be as easy as `int index = year - 1907`, assuming year 1907 is the element with index 0.

If the menthod you used `Years[i].calculateAvgRain()` works, then you probably just need to adjust that `i` (as mentioned above). You don't need a loop then.

Since you're asking a question it is probably something else that is the problem. 
I'll assume you have 100x12 array with years as rows and month rain data in the columns.

```
public double calculateAverage(int year) {
    int index = year - 1907; //extract 1907 into a CONSTANT or some other variable if possible

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (double monthRain : years[index]) { //is `years` visible?
        sum += monthRain;
    }

    return sum / years[index].length; //`years[index].length` should be 12, but maybe you have a blank month data?
}
```

Please, do correct me and clarify the problem in a bit more detail.